# CSS transform above surrounding divs

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms, owl-carousel

I'm trying to expand owl carousel items on hover (and eventually display content on click). It's kind of mostly there, but I need the expanding of each item to be on top of the other items without disturbing them. I've seen similar questions answered using position relative & absolute for various surrounding divs, but so far setting item to Absolute makes them all disappear. I have a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ThePixelPixie/pen/jARXAo) for working on this. Any help that can be afforded would be hugely appreciated.

(as a side, at one point I'd had the sub-title nicely sitting at the bottom of the item box, but somewhere along the line that went away. I'd love to know why since I didn't touch the css for that div.)

I'm not sure why I'm being told that a link to Codepen must be accompanied by code. I thought that was the point of using sites like CodePen, so bunches of code don't have to be annoyingly formatted here.  So, here's just a little code. If you really do need it all entered here I shall, but was hoping to avoid that.

```
<div class="wrapper-with-margin">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
        <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(imagepath.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(217,48,19);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
            <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-4x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Profile</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
        <div id="Profile" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
            <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
            <p>Hutt organa maul wicket. Binks droid wampa ewok bespin skywalker hutt. Windu darth coruscant moff wicket fisto solo cade. Amidala jabba calrissian alderaan solo dagobah gonk. Hutt han darth kessel lobot jade. Padmé mandalore luke kenobi. Owen hutt chewbacca vader leia solo baba dagobah. Watto jinn greedo kit sidious wookiee. Yavin anakin kit kessel padmé darth jinn zabrak gonk. Darth wedge jawa yoda skywalker bespin bespin fett. Kessel tatooine mara padmé. Sidious organa obi-wan wicket solo. Sidious gonk leia moff luke lars skywalker yavin coruscant.</p>
            <p>Luke qui-gon moff fett antilles. Sidious antilles organa wookiee. Coruscant dagobah qui-gonn kit sidious baba yoda skywalker wampa. Dooku moff cade lobot calamari. Gonk ponda kamino dantooine owen luke luke. Sith hutt chewbacca dantooine ponda. Windu kit hutt mon chewbacca endor hoth droid. Organa ackbar calamari hutt darth owen chewbacca. Jade anakin tatooine gonk ben wedge antilles lars. Jar secura moff jade darth. Yoda zabrak kenobi kessel amidala. Yavin fett yoda ventress vader. Cade ackbar maul hoth.</p>
            <p>Hoth alderaan ponda solo. Lobot skywalker tatooine jango. Mara jinn tatooine kessel skywalker moff. Ben palpatine alderaan zabrak sith endor skywalker utapau moff. Jawa wedge dooku ponda ventress wedge. Wedge sidious han kessel wampa moff binks mon. Hutt solo qui-gonn maul fett hutt padmé cade ackbar. Windu wicket cade endor r2-d2 mon skywalker amidala dagobah. Luke tatooine hutt moff darth dagobah. Darth moff darth luke. Sith luke calamari mace skywalker. Lando anakin fisto padmé wicket wampa yoda organa yavin.</p>
            <p>Twi&#8217;lek jango solo vader fisto obi-wan darth antilles. Yavin organa luke bothan leia skywalker bothan vader organa. Calrissian vader grievous mothma. Moff wedge ben mandalore organa hutt boba darth. Dantooine mace dantooine mothma solo lars owen organa droid. Windu qui-gonn luke antilles gonk. Solo skywalker lando grievous. Darth jinn kamino yavin sith calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi&#8217;lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Do I still need to provide code sample even if I am providing fiddle link?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302329/)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to expand blocks with the `.owl-item` class instead of theirs children with the `.item` class.

1. Add [the `addClassActive: true` option](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) to the script:

   > Add "active" classes on visible items. Works with any numbers of items on screen.
2. Remove `.item:hover` from CSS:

```css
    .item:hover {
      width: calc(100% + 25%) !important;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
      -o-transform: scale(1.4);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
      transform: scale(1.4);
      -webkit-transform-origin: left 0;
      -moz-transform-origin: left 0;
      -o-transform-origin: left 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: left 0;
      transform-origin: left 0;
      z-index: 10000;
    }

    .item:hover .tile_element .tile_subtitle {
      width: calc(100% + 25%) !important;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      -o-transform: scale(1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
      -webkit-transform-origin: left 0;
      -moz-transform-origin: left 0;
      -o-transform-origin: left 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: left 0;
      transform-origin: left 0;
      z-index: 10000;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

3. Add this code instead:

```css
    .owl-item:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
         -moz-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
          -ms-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
           -o-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
              transform: scale(1.2) !important;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
         -moz-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
          -ms-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
           -o-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
              transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
    }

    .owl-item:first-child:hover,
    .owl-item:not(.active)+.owl-item.active:hover {
      -webkit-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
         -moz-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
          -ms-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
           -o-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
              transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

Please check the result. Is it what you want to achieve?

http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/LkovRb

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var carousel = $("#owl-demo");
  carousel.owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='fa fa-arrow-left fa-3x'></i>",
      "<i class='fa fa-arrow-right fa-3x'></i>"
    ],
    lazyLoad: true,
    pagination: false,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1,
        nav: true
      },
      600: {
        items: 3,
        nav: false
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5,
        nav: true,
        loop: false
      }
    },
    addClassActive: true
  });

  $('.link').on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
      $this.removeAttr('style').removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
      $this.css('background', '#7fc242').addClass('clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

footer {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

footer p {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Styling Next and Prev buttons */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  display: inline;
  /*IE7 life-saver */
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
  /*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Clickable class fix problem with hover on touch devices */


/* Use it for non-touch hover action */

.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-buttons div:hover {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
  /*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Styling Pagination*/

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page {
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
  *display: inline;
  /*IE7 life-saver */
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span {
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px 7px;
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=50);
  /*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page.active span,
.owl-theme .owl-controls.clickable .owl-page:hover span {
  filter: Alpha(Opacity=100);
  /*IE7 fix*/
  opacity: 1;
}


/* If PaginationNumbers is true */

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-page span.owl-numbers {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}


/* preloading images */


/*.owl-item.loading {
 min-height: 150px;
 background: url(AjaxLoader.gif) no-repeat center center
}*/

#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  /*margin: 3px;
 border: 1px black;*/
}

.wrapper-with-margin {
  margin: 0px 50px;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons div {
  position: absolute;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev {
  left: -90px;
  top: calc(50vh - 160px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-prev:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next {
  right: -90px;
  top: calc(50vh - 160px);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) !important;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.owl-theme .owl-controls .owl-buttons .owl-next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
}

.owl-demo {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  /*padding: 30px 0px;*/
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 13px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.owl-item:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
       -o-transform: scale(1.2) !important;
          transform: scale(1.2) !important;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
     -moz-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
       -o-transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
          transform-origin: 100% 20% 0;
}
.owl-item:first-child:hover,
.owl-item:not(.active)+.owl-item.active:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
     -moz-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
      -ms-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
       -o-transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
          transform-origin: 0 20% 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

.tile_color {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.item:hover .tile_color.tile_element {
  opacity: .7;
}

.tile_element {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.tile_image {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
  /* Old WebKit */
  filter: grayscale(1);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.tile_content {
  height: calc(50% + 5px);
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.tile_icon {
  top: calc(25% - 15px);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.tile_title {
  top: calc(50% + 0px);
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
}

.tile_subtitle {
  bottom: 22px;
}

.tile_content i,
.tile_content div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
}

.home h3:before {
  content: '';
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .7);
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

html {
  font-family: Open Sans, Array, Array, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13;
}

body {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

a .style-svg {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

footer p {
  color: #777777;
  font-size: 10px;
}

footer p a {
  color: #c4c4c4;
}

footer p a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.home h2 {
  font-family: 'Herr Von Muellerhoff', serif;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 38px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.home h3 {
  font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-min-css' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='owl-style-css' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='owl-theme-css' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='owl-transitions-css' href='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.transitions.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='acfgfs-enqueue-fonts-css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Herr+Von+Muellerhoff%7CRaleway%3A100%2C100italic%2C200%2C200italic%2C300%2C300italic%2C400%2Citalic%2C500%2C500italic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic%2C900%2C900italic%7COpen+Sans%3A300%2C300italic%2C400%2Citalic%2C600%2C600italic%2C700%2C700italic%2C800%2C800italic&#038;subset=latin-ext%2Clatin%2Cgreek%2Ccyrillic-ext%2Ccyrillic%2Cgreek-ext%2Cvietnamese&#038;ver=4.6'
  type='text/css' media='all' />

<body class="home">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="wrapper-with-margin">
        <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/IMAG0286CROPPED-919x1024-919x1024.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(217,48,19);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-asterisk fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>About Me</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Profile</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Profile" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238); position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
              <p><img src="http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/sharon-150x150.jpg" alt="sharon" width="150" height="150" class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-52" />Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi’lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/resume-1024x731.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(243,189,0);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>My Skills</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Resumé</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Resumé" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
              <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi’lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/105__.png);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(0,0,255);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>My Work</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Portfolio</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Portfolio" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
              <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi’lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/android-app-developer-Specialist11-1024x576.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(86,211,83);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>My Clients</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Testimonials</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Testimonials" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
              <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi’lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/Carroll-Creek-Park-Abloom-Frederick-MD-1024x768.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(102,102,102);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Contact</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Contact" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
              <p>Lucas ipsum dolor sit amet skywalker moff padmé mon skywalker moff moff luuke binks jabba. Mon mustafar c-3p0 mustafar antilles calamari organa. Solo wedge moff gonk c-3p0 dantooine chewbacca darth. Lando darth coruscant kessel qui-gonn mara maul dantooine. Jabba organa solo skywalker hutt kenobi qui-gonn. Luuke vader darth binks alderaan ahsoka wicket antilles wedge. Chewbacca leia tusken raider organa calrissian. Thrawn baba solo moff. Windu darth kashyyyk hutt kashyyyk gamorrean maul. Skywalker kit moff wedge coruscant amidala.</p>
calamari fisto ewok. Kit mara anakin darth secura jade jar twi’lek bothan. Bespin darth hutt ponda darth. Darth qui-gonn sidious lars sidious kessel.</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="item owl-lazy link">
            <div class="tile_image tile_element" style="background-image: url(http://ccharacter.themedev.thepixelpixie.com/wp-c0nt3nt/uploads/2016/08/Call-Center-1024x683.jpg);"></div>
            <div class="tile_color tile_element" style="background-color: rgb(155,89,182);"></div>
            <div class="tile_content tile_element">
              <div class="tile_icon">
                <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-4x"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_title">
                <h2>Service</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tile_subtitle">
                <h3>Login / Account</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tile_element tile_effect"></div>
            <div id="Login / Account" class="with_fading mCustomScrollbar mCS-autoHide mCS_no_scrollbar" style="position: relative; overflow: visible; top: 0px; width: 0px; display: none; left: -100%; min-height: 400px;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End Row -->

  </div>
  <!-- end container-fluid -->

  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>
</body>
```